# Reading a JSON in python and converting it to dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

Suppose I have a JSON file as follows,

```
{u'level': u'INFO',
 u'message': {"method":"someMethod","params":{"frameId":"9.6","loaderId":"3.2","requestId":"4.6"}}
u'timestamp': 654789L}
```

For parsing this into dataframe, for the first level, I am able to do `data[1]['level']`, `data[1]['message']`, `data[1]['timestamp']`. But I want to go deeper into the message and I am trying, `data[1]['message']['method']` or `data[1]['message']['params']` which is throwing me error.

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

There is a difference in quotes between the first level and second levels where the first level has single quotes and second level has double quotes. Can anybody tell me how to reach to the method or params parameter here? Also the best way to parse everything into a dataframe?

Thanks

Comment: Try running `data[1].keys()` and `data[1]['message'].keys()`.

Comment: data[1].keys() gives [u'timestamp', u'message', u'level'] but data[1]['message'].keys gives AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: Your first example is not JSON, but a Python dictionary converted to a string. It's also wrong, cause you're missing a comma after the two }}'s at the 2nd line. You should also include a full (working) code example of what you're trying to do, because what you're saying is the error doesn't match your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.read_json` this will automatically read the file into a DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_json('test.json')
```

but the data you show in the question is not in valid JSON format. For the correct format please see this [example](http://www.w3schools.com/json/). To check if your file is in valid JSON format you can also use this [validator](http://jsonlint.com/). The valid JSON format of your data would look like this:

```
[{
    "level": "INFO",
    "message": [{
        "method": "someMethod",
        "params": [{
            "frameId": "9.6",
            "loaderId": "3.2",
            "requestId": "4.6"
        }]
    }],
    "timestamp": "654789 L"
}]
```